# How to read from request then use that result to do POST request then process its results

Tags: rest, proxy, go

I'm trying to read from request then use that result to do POST request to another endpoint then process its results then return its results in JSON.

I have below code so far:

```
// POST 
func (u *UserResource) authenticate(request *restful.Request, response *restful.Response) {
    Api := Api{url: "http://api.com/api"}
    usr := new(User)
    err := request.ReadEntity(&usr)
    if err != nil {
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    api_resp, err := http.Post(Api.url, "text/plain", bytes.NewBuffer(usr))
    if err != nil {
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer api_resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(api_resp.Body)
    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    err = xml.Unmarshal(body, usr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
//  result, err := json.Marshal(usr)
//  response.Write(result)
    response.WriteEntity(&usr)
    fmt.Printf("Name: %q\n", usr.UserName)
}
```

I'm using [Go Restful](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful) package for Writes and Reads.

I'm getting this error when I compile the file:

```
src\login.go:59: cannot use usr (type *User) as type []byte in argument to bytes.NewBuffer
```

What would be the best way to solve this issue so I can do a POST with payload correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go - how do I dump the struct into the byte array without reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854125/go-how-do-i-dump-the-struct-into-the-byte-array-without-reflection)

Comment: @DewyBroto How can I encode it in XML then change to `[]byte` format for sending as POST? I tried Print with request.Request.Body but it's outputting nothing...

Comment: @DewyBroto I think the problem is `ReadEntity` as when I do `fmt.Println` to print out `usr.UserName` for example it prints out `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to marshal your data structure to slice of bytes. Something like this:

```
usrXmlBytes, err := xml.Marshal(usr)
if err != nil {
    response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
}
api_resp, err := http.Post(Api.url, "text/plain", bytes.NewReader(usrXmlBytes))
```

Comment: If you need json serialization, use `encoding/json` instead of `encoding/xml`

Comment: I need to get JSON request from client and convert it into XML then do a POST request to another end point. Then I need to re-parse the results into JSON then write back to the client

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. It seems like ReadEntity doesn't work properly as I did usr.Token but came with no results but when I manually added string valid XML instead of `bytes.NewBuffer(usr)` it works somehow

Comment: maybe because usr is a pointer already? Try that: `err := request.ReadEntity(usr)`

Comment: Yes it works! But I just found out that `ioutil.ReadAll` returns something like this `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n<!DOCTYPE api SYSTEM \"api.dtd\">\n<oxip version=\"6.0\">\n   ` How do I make it so it doesn't escape but encode properly in XML?

Comment: I do not understand what exactly you mean. How you got that output?

Comment: Actually sorry this is correct. I just need to manipulate JSON payload into valid XML structure before doing a POST request to another endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

`http.Post` takes an [io.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) as the third argument.  You could implement `io.Reader` on your `User` type or more simply serialize your data and use the `bytes` pkg to to implement `io.Reader`

```
b, err := json.Marshal(usr)
if err != nil {
    response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
}
api_resp, err := http.Post(Api.url, "text/plain", bytes.NewReader(b))
```