# Golang serialize and deserialize back

Tags: serialization, go, deserialization

What's the best way (completeness and performance) in Golang to serialize and deserialize a struct to string and vice versa?

for example, if I have this struct:

```
struct Session {
   Properties map[string]interface{}
   Permissions []int64
}
```

I want to store it on [Redis](http://github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis) and fetch it back. I have tried to save, int and string, it's fine, but how to store struct object?

```
conn := redisConnectors.Get()

// set example

_, err := conn.Do(`SETEX`, `uid_key`, EXPIRE_SEC, user_id)
_, err = conn.Do(`SETEX`, `email_key`, EXPIRE_SEC, login_email)

// get example

user_id, err := redis.Int64(conn.Do(`GET`, `uid_key`))
login_email, err := redis.String(conn.Do(`GET`, `email_key`))
```

Comment: For reference, the [boj/redistore](https://github.com/boj/redistore/blob/master/redistore.go) library serialises session data to Redis using either `encoding/gob` or `encoding/json` and just saves the raw []byte slice to Redis: https://github.com/boj/redistore/blob/master/redistore.go#L313

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using [gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) and [base64](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/) could solve the problem, for example:

```
import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/gob"
    "bytes"
)

type SX map[string]interface{}

// go binary encoder
func ToGOB64(m SX) string {
    b := bytes.Buffer{}
    e := gob.NewEncoder(&b)
    err := e.Encode(m)
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(`failed gob Encode`, err) }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b.Bytes())
}

// go binary decoder
func FromGOB64(str string) SX {
    m := SX{}
    by, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str)
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(`failed base64 Decode`, err); }
    b := bytes.Buffer{}
    b.Write(by)
    d := gob.NewDecoder(&b)
    err = d.Decode(&m)
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(`failed gob Decode`, err); }
    return m
}
```

and when you need to serialize custom struct or type (for example `Session` struct), just add these lines:

```
func init() {
    gob.Register(SX{})
    gob.Register(Session{}) 
}
```

if you want to use [other serialization format](//kokizzu.blogspot.com/2020/12/golang-serialization-benchmark-2020.html) (2020) or this [benchmark](//github.com/kokizzu/kokizzu-benchmark/tree/master/ser-deser) (2022) for dynamic structure

Comment: You shouldn't even need to base64 encode the result from gob - you can just save the `[]byte` to Redis. Faster, too. JSON encoding also benches a little faster than `encoding/gob` although it's unlikely to be a substantial/noticeable difference in most apps.

Comment: I've tried JSON encoding before, it's the reason I asked this question, but it failed to convert `map[int]..` or decode correctly, for example: `map[string]bool` when encoded and decoded back would become `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: For `map[int]...` you'll need to satisfy the `json.Marshaller` and `json.Unmarshaller` interfaces as JSON keys are strings. Your `map[string]bool` should have worked fine though.

Answer (score 16):

Serialization of a struct generally uses the [`encoding`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/) package. However, that will work for public fields only. If you also need to serialize private fields, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854659/6309) as an alternative.
You have several encoding choices (binary, text, [json as in this example for a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8271160/6309), xml, etc.). For example, the project [`cupcake/rdb`](https://github.com/cupcake/rdb) uses [`encoding/binary`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) to implement parsing and encoding of the [Redis](http://redis.io/) [RDB file format](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/blob/master/docs/RDB_File_Format.textile) (a binary representation of the in-memory store).
Another example is [`guregu/rediscache`](https://github.com/guregu/rediscache), a small library for caching data in Redis.

Comment: The comment about "public field only" was important.