# How to publish and consume make(map[string]string) in rabbitmq go lang

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have multiple objects of key-value type which i need to send to RabbitMQ and hence forward would consume them. So, after going through this [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-go.html) link. It only tells the way to publish a simple plain text message. Can anyone tell me how to publish and consume map objects in RabbitMQ go lang?

```
     m := make(map[string]string)
     m["col1"] = "004999010640000"
     m["col2"] = "awadwaw"
     m["col3"] = "13"  

     err = ch.Publish(
        "EventCaptureData-Exchange", // exchange
        q.Name + "Key",          // routing key
        true,           // mandatory                            
        false,           // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "?????",
            Body:        ????,
        })
```

Comment: `map[string]string` is a fairly simple data structure, why not use json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize your Go object to eg. base64 text before publishing it. In your consumer, you then deserialize it to get back your initial object. See "[Golang serialize and deserialize back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020070/golang-serialize-and-deserialize-back)" for an example in Go.

For the content type, I'm not sure what is the most appropriate. `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: since the type is mostly string data (`map[string]string`), json is going to be more compact than a gob in base64.

Comment: I agree, JSON is probably a better choice for many reasons (easier debugging, possibility to read and interpret it from another language, etc.). I just mentionned base64 here because I found an example quickly. I'm not a Go developer so I couldn't prepare a JSON-based example.

Answer (score 6):

It's so simple. You can use [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) and [bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) packages to serialize and deserialize messages. Prepared this example for you:

```
type Message map[string]interface{}

func serialize(msg Message) ([]byte, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(&b)
    err := encoder.Encode(msg)
    return b.Bytes(), err
}

func deserialize(b []byte) (Message, error) {
    var msg Message
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(b)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(buf)
    err := decoder.Decode(&msg)
    return msg, err
}
```

Yeah, basically that's it. Body field in [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html) library is byte array, therefore all you need are just converting to/from your data structure to/from byte array.

Comment: Works great. This should be stated somewhere in the documentation.