# How to serialize DynamoDB LastEvaluatedKey to string

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go, aws-sdk-go-v2

Have a requirement of transferring the LastEvaluatedKey returned from the query output as the response of a paginated API call so that the users can request the next page with the LastEvaluatedKey.
Is it possible to convert with aws-sdk-go-v2 ?

Have tried to marshal and unmarshal using json but it was not working

```
lek := map[string]types.AttributeValue{
    "num":  &types.AttributeValueMemberN{Value: "1"},
    "text": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "text"},
}
barray, err := json.Marshal(lek)
if err != nil {
  fmt.println(err)
}

lekDecoded := map[string]types.AttributeValue{}
err = json.Unmarshal(barray, &lekDecoded)
if err != nil {
 fmt.println(err)
}
```

This always keeps failing to decode it back to map[string]types.AttributeValue

Comment: The LastEvaluatedKey is just a string. What code do you have that is not working?

Comment: @luk2302 updated a sample code which i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastEvaluatedKey` is provided in plain text in the response. If you want to encode it, you can do so using base64 for example. You can choose any type of encoding so long as you decode before supplying back to the next paged request.

#### Encode LEK

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name test \
--limit 1 \
--query LastEvaluatedKey | base64
```

```
ewogICAgImlkIjogewogICAgICAgICJTIjogIjR3OG5pWnBpTXk2cXoxbW50RkE1dSIKICAgIH0KfQo
```

#### Decode encoded LEK

```
echo ewogICAgImlkIjogewogICAgICAgICJTIjogIjR3OG5pWnBpTXk2cXoxbW50RkE1dSIKICAgIH0KfQo | base64 --decode
```

```
{
    "id": {
        "S": "4w8niZpiMy6qz1mntFA5u"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is their any recommend way to do it using aws-sdk-go-v2?

Comment: Have you tried GOB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020070/golang-serialize-and-deserialize-back